# Unable to sum grouped values correctly using RDLC

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer

Suppose my data source is a table of normalized data where each row represents a truckload of grain harvested from a farm field like this.

```
Field Acres Bushels
A     50    500
A     50    600
B     40    550
B     40    600
B     40    500
C     50    500
C     50    450
```

I would like my RDLC report to give a summary of this information as follows:

```
Field    Acres Total Bushels
A        50    1100
B        40    1650
C        50     950
Totals  140    3600
```

I've tried a couple of different approaches (grouping on Field and grouping on both Field and Acres) but in each case I get the wrong total 320 for the total acres for my three fields.

I'm currently using a single level of grouping which groups on both Field and Acres.  I then add a total row, in which I would like to display the sum of the *grouped values* for acres, but it seems that I'm unable to use [scoping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255256.aspx) to accomplish this, since it is illegal to refer to an inner scope from an outer one.  Specifically, I get an error if I try `Sum(Fields!Acres.Value, "Field")` because the grouping on farm field is *inside* the overall totals grouping.

It also seems to be illegal to use an aggregate on a ReportItem.  That is, if I name the textbox containing acres, say 'txtAcres', the expression `Sum(ReportItem!txtAcres.Value)` is not allowed in my totals row.

Please note: I believe that any solution that involves summing *distinct* values will give the incorrect total acres of 90 (since we have two fields with exactly 50 acres)

Comment: `I've tried a couple of different approaches` Your post is the right place to show what you have tried.

Comment: @Eser - I thought I had done so.  The approaches I tried were using scoping and aggregating on the ReportItem (i.e. the textbox containing Acres").  I'll edit my post to try to clarify...

Answer (score 0):

I'm submitting this as an answer, but I consider it to be more of a workaround.  I'm still hoping that there is a clean solution in RDLC to this common and simple problem.

I added another column to my data source called PartialAcres defined like this:

```
t.Acres * t.Bushels / (Select sum(Bushels) from Loads where Field = T.Field) 
as PartialAcres    

Field Acres Bushels PartialAcres
A     50    500     22.7272
A     50    600     27.2727
B     40    550     13.3333
B     40    600     14.5454
B     40    500     12.1212
C     50    500     26.3158
C     50    450     23.6842
```

Now I can use the expression `Sum(Fields!PartialAcres.Value)` at any level of grouping to get the correct total Acres.